# socket - close(2) send RST packet instead of FIN packet

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I wrote a simple client and a server, basically the client first connect to the server and then disconnect with `close(2)`, which looks like:

```
/* setting server address and other stuff */
...

connect();
close();
```

there's no other actions between call to `connect()` and `close()`.

the server accepts connection and uses `epoll(7)` to monitor EPOLLOUT event. When epoll reports EPOLLOUT, server writes 1 byte to client.

```
     nev = epoll_wait(ep, events, 10, -1);

     for (int i=0; i<nev; i++) {
         std::cout << "ready, events: " << std::hex
             << events[i].events << std::dec << std::endl;
         if (events[i].data.fd == sockfd) {
             int connfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &len);
             if (connfd < 0) {
                 std::cout << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
                 exit(0);
             }
             std::cout << "accpeted\n";

             struct epoll_event ev;
             ev.events = EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT|EPOLLRDHUP|EPOLLHUP;
             ev.data.fd = connfd;
             epoll_ctl(ep, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, connfd, &ev);
         } else { 
             if (events[i].events & EPOLLOUT) {
                 write(events[i].data.fd, "1", 1);
                 sleep(1);
             }
         }
    }
```

tcpdump here, 9999 is the server:

```
11:52:11.411988 IP localhost.37776 > localhost.9999: Flags [S], seq 2786125487, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 34912846 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:52:11.412013 IP localhost.9999 > localhost.37776: Flags [S.], seq 1338547838, ack 2786125488, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 34912846 ecr 34912846,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:52:11.412035 IP localhost.37776 > localhost.9999: Flags [.], ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 34912846 ecr 34912846], length 0
11:52:11.413476 IP localhost.9999 > localhost.37776: Flags [P.], seq 1:2, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 34912847 ecr 34912846], length 1
11:52:11.414869 IP localhost.37776 > localhost.9999: Flags [.], ack 2, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 34912847 ecr 34912847], length 0
11:52:11.415882 IP localhost.37776 > localhost.9999: Flags [R.], seq 1, ack 2, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 34912847 ecr 34912847], length 0
```

the last packet suggests that client send a RST packet to close the connection. I didn't set the SO_LINGER option, why does this happen?

Comment: Because the client didn't do any reads. It closed the socket on which there was still unread pending data.

Comment: @user207421 is this a standard or implementation-dependent?

Comment: it's defined in [RFC1122](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1122#page-87), more discussion in [RFC2525](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2525#page-50)

Comment: You should `shutdown()` a socket first, then `recv()` on it until there is nothing left to read, and then finally `close()` it. `shutdown()` will send a FIN, and `recv()` will receive the peer's FIN.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The implementation of `tcp_close` on the kernel, in the file `net/ipv4/tcp.c`. 
The kernel is explained as follows:

```
/* As outlined in RFC 2525, section 2.17, we send a RST here because
 * data was lost. To witness the awful effects of the old behavior of
 * always doing a FIN, run an older 2.1.x kernel or 2.0.x, start a bulk
 * GET in an FTP client, suspend the process, wait for the client to
 * advertise a zero window, then kill -9 the FTP client, wheee...
 * Note: timeout is always zero in such a case.
 */
if (unlikely(tcp_sk(sk)->repair)) {
    sk->sk_prot->disconnect(sk, 0);
} else if (data_was_unread) {
    /* Unread data was tossed, zap the connection. */
    NET_INC_STATS(sock_net(sk), LINUX_MIB_TCPABORTONCLOSE);
    tcp_set_state(sk, TCP_CLOSE);
    tcp_send_active_reset(sk, sk->sk_allocation);
}
```

Reference: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/tcp.c?h=v4.19.26#n2348

Comment: This link is unstable because it's not versioned, and its a klunky mirror. Could you link a fixed version (so line number remains valid) on git.kernel.org?